# How can I activate tooltip only when ellipsis?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I make 2 names. In full page, I can see both names so no tooltip nor ellipsis, its ok. But, when I resize, the ellipsis shows up, but the tooltip doesn't activate until when I reload the page.

```
const Name = () => {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const [tooltip, setTooltip] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!tooltip && ref.current.offsetWidth > ref.current.scrollWidth) {
      setTooltip(true);
    }
  }, [tooltip]);

  if (tooltip) {
    return (
      <Tooltip
        styles={nameTooltipStyle}
        content={name.map(nm => (
          <div key={nm.id} className="tooltipName">
            <div className="label">
              <li className="list">{nm.name}</li>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      >
        <div ref={ref} className="name">
          {Name}
        </div>
      </Tooltip>
    );
  }
  return (
    <div ref={ref} className="name">
      {name}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to activate the tooltip when window is resized, you can use the `resize` event listener:-

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
    if (!tooltip && ref.current.offsetWidth > ref.current.scrollWidth) {
        setTooltip(true);
    }
});
```

Please note that this event is fired many times when the window is being resized. I would encourage you to use concept of `debouncing` to optimize the performance.

Comment: Hi, thanks for ur answer! But, I mean, When there 5 names in full page, I dont need tooltip and ellipsis, because I can see the all names and when I resize the page there become ellipsis and tooltip, but tooltip is not working, but when I reload the page, it's starting work

Comment: @Marcus Even if there is only one name on the page and the window is resized, to activate the tooltip you need to listen for the `resize` event and do `setTooltip`.